# How do you convert -$\pi\ln|\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$| to $\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

What is the step by step algebraic manipulation of the left hand to achieve the right hand?

-$\pi\ln|\frac{\sqrt2}{2}$| = $\frac{\pi}{2}\ln2?$

Comment: Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or be put on hold. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and **include your work and thoughts on the problem.**
 These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 3):

**Hint**:

1. $\left|\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\right| = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{2^{\frac12}}{2^1} = 2^{-\frac12}$, or, another way to get the same result, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2} = \frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} = 2^{-\frac12}$
2. $\ln(a^b) = b\cdot \ln(a)$.

Comment: Just a typo: The third denominator is $2^1$.